# Looking for a reference book, or book chapter to learn about piezoelectricity

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, piezoelectric

I'm looking for an introduction to the treatment of [piezoelectricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity), specially in semiconductors emphasizing the dependence on the orientation of the unit cell and the interactive effects with the electron-holes pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard book is

> Introduction to Solid State Physics (8th ed. 2005, ISBN 0-471-41526-X)
>   by Charles Kittel.

Your question should be answered in chapter 13. All that is said there should in principle be applicable to semiconductors. But since their bandgap is lower than in dielectrics you might have a problem measuring this (they might just be too conductive an the effect is lost).

On the other hand in your prototypical GaAs crystals there is a rather strong effect in the (111) direction due to the stacking of Ga and As layers and their asymmetric response to stress...

Note though that this has nothing to do with electron/hole pairs. This is strictly a polarisation phenomenon.